# Same random number sequence generated by Verilog-A code when running the code consecutively

Tags: verilog, random-seed

Recently I have to use Verilog-A to generate a set of random numbers (sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ). Statistically, each of them has mean=0 and std=1, and sigmaX^2+sigmaY^2+sigmaZ^2=1. The following code in test_solver.va file is writen in Verilog-A to realize such random numebr set at each time step:

```
`include "disciplines.h"
`include "constants.h"

module test_va(p,n,mb,mc,md,me,mf,mg);
    
    inout p,n;
    output mb,mc,md,me,mf,mg;
    
    electrical p,n,mb,mc,md,me,mf,mg;

    real randomX,randomY,randomZ;                         // Gaussian random variables with mean = 0, stdev = 1
    real sigmaX,sigmaY,sigmaZ;                            // Normalized thermal noise vector components
    integer seedX,seedY,seedZ;                            // Seed variables for RNG
    integer random_seed;
    
//------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Define mag(x, y, z)
//------------------------------------------------------------------//
 analog function real mag;
  input x, y, z;
  real x, y, z;
  begin
        mag = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));
  end
 endfunction
    
    analog begin
        random_seed = 1;
        
        seedX  = $random+random_seed;
        seedY  = $random+random_seed;
        seedZ  = $random+random_seed;

        randomX = $rdist_normal(seedX, 0.0, 1.0);
        randomY = $rdist_normal(seedY, 0.0, 1.0);
        randomZ = $rdist_normal(seedZ, 0.0, 1.0);

        sigmaX = randomX/mag(randomX, randomY, randomZ);
        sigmaY = randomY/mag(randomX, randomY, randomZ);
        sigmaZ = randomZ/mag(randomX, randomY, randomZ);
        
        V(mb) <+ randomX;
        V(mc) <+ randomY;
        V(md) <+ randomZ;
        V(me) <+ sigmaX;
        V(mf) <+ sigmaY;
        V(mg) <+ sigmaZ;

    end
endmodule
```

I used HSPICE 2019 to test the random number output at each simulation step, by running the folloing test_solver.sp file:

```
Title Simple 

.option post=1
.option probe=0
*.option runlvl=4
.option ingold=2
*.option accurate=1
*.option method=bdf
*.option bdfrtol=1e-5
*.option bdfatol=1e-5
.option numdgt=4
.option brief
.option measfile=1
.option lis_new=1
.option vaopts=str('-G')
.save

.hdl ./test_solver.va

vin 1 0 PULSE(0 0.5 2NS 1NS 1NS 10NS 20NS)
X 1 0 2 3 4 5 6 7  test_va 

.tran 0.01n 20.0n 1E-10 uic
.print tran V(1) V(2) V(3) V(4) V(5) V(6) V(7)
.end
```

However, I noticed that it always generates an identical random number set (sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ) if I run in HSPICE consecutively. But my requirement is to have different random number sets when running the same code consecutively.

I also noticed that if I change `random_seed=1` in the test_solver.va file, for example, to `random_seed=2` (or 3 or 4 ...) and run in HSPICE, it will generate a different random number set than before. But it still generates the same set when running the same code consecutively.

So I wonder if there is anything wrong with my test_solver.va code, or we have to change "random_seed=1" every time. Then it might not be easy to realize if I integrate this code into others and run many times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pseudo-random number generators are deterministic. That means if you start with the same seed you will always get the same result.

I'm not aware of any way to do what you want directly in Verilog-A. I think that you will need to write your own function in 'C'. One technique that is often used is to call a high resolution timer and assume that the time in micro- or nanoseconds is essentially random. Alternatively you can call a function like `getrandom()`.

The next problem is getting the 'C' random value back to your Verilog-A. I'm not familiar with HSPICE, but this can be done with Verilog PLI on some other simulators.

Alternatively you could wrap your simulation in a shell script and do something like this

- script: read /dev/urandom and write a random number to a file
- run hspice
- in your Verilog-A use a system task like $fread to read the file that the script produced